# Terraform 0.12 AWS resource containing JSON built from variable

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hcl

To provision tag policies in an AWS organization, I need to build the JSON `content` from variables. Management of tag policies, scp, etc. shall be centralized, so changes can be applied everywhere: Renaming, adding, removing tags, etc.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-west-1"
}
```

The problem at hand I am facing is: How would I build the JSON object?

Example variable/ tag map:

```
# tag_policies.tf
variable "resource_tags" {
  description = "Central resource tags"
  type = list( object( {
    name = string
    tags = map(string)
  } ) )
  default = [
    {
      name = "Environment"
      tags = {
        prod = "crn::env:prod"
        lab = "crn::env:lab"
        dev = "crn::env:dev"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I have tried so far is to use HCL template tags, but I end up with one `,` comma too much when iterating through the map of tag names. This works fine for the `join()` with the sub-map of tag names, but does not workout if I try to wrap the template markup. *Why did I try this? Because I ran out of ideas.*

```
# vars.tf
resource "aws_organizations_policy" "root-tag-policy" {
  name = "RootTagPolicy"
  type = "TAG_POLICY"

  content = <<CONTENT
{
  "tags": {
    %{ for tag in var.resource_tags_env ~}
      "${tag.name}": {
        "tag_key": {
          "@@assign": "${tag.name}",
          "@@operators_allowed_for_child_policies": [ "@@none" ]
        },
        "tag_value": { "@@assign": [ "${join( ", ", values( tag.tags ) )}" ] }
      },
    %{ endfor ~}
  }
}
CONTENT
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution actually was quite simple: Iterate of the tags using a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions) and enclose it with curly braces `{ … }` to return an object (`=>` returns tuples).

Finally `jsonencode()` cares about converting the HCL `key = value` syntax to proper JSON.

```
resource "aws_organizations_policy" "root-tag-policy" {
  name = "RootTagPolicy"
  type = "TAG_POLICY"

  content = jsonencode( [ for key, tag in var.resource_tags: {
    "${tag.name}" = {
      "tag_key" = {
        "@@assign" = tag.name,
        "@@operators_allowed_for_child_policies" = [ "@@none" ]
      },
      "tag_value" = { "@@assign" = [ join( ", ", values( tag.tags ) ) ] }
    }
  } ] )
}
```

**EDIT** This still does not work, as I forgot that the whole JSON object needs to get wrapped inside a `tags: {}`.

Answer (score 1):

kaiser's answer shows a good general approach: build a suitable data structure and then pass it to [`jsonencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html) to get a valid JSON string from it.

Here's an example that I think matches what the string template in the original question would've produced:

```
  content = jsonencode({
    tags = {
      for tag in var.resource_tags_env : tag.name => {
        tag_key = {
          "@@assign" = tag.name
          "@@operators_allowed_for_child_policies" = ["@@none"]
        }
        tag_value = {
          "@@assign" = values(tag.tags)
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

I'm not familiar with the `aws_organizations_policy` resource type so I'm sorry if I got some details wrong here, but hopefully you can adapt the above example to generate the JSON data structure you need.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by and answering, Martin! You pushed me to the missing piece that could not understand from reading the docs: `key => { …data… }` it is. I'll add another answer to show how I finally solved it (without using a `name` key). Couldn't have done it without your answer tough!

Answer (score 0):

After reading @martin-atkins answer, I finally understood how the `for` works for `objects` and `maps`. The var *before* the `=>` arrow actually is part of the resulting object. (This highly confused me as I compared it to other languages arrow functions and arguments.)

The first part of the process is to build a map of maps. The main reason is that I don't want to have a *convention* of a `name` key in a map of variables. This might lead to handling of conventions later on, what should be avoided at all costs as it is a possible trap if one does not pay close attention or is aware of it. So the `key` actually is the `name` now.

#### Data Structure

```
variable "resource_tags" {
  description = "Central resource tags"
  type = map(
    map(string)
  )
  default = {
    Environment = {
      common = "grn::env:common"
      prod = "grn::env:prod"
      stage = "grn::env:stage"
      dev = "grn::env:dev"
      demo = "grn::env:demo"
      lab = "grn::env:lab"
    },
    Foo = {
      bar = "baz"
    }
  }
}
```

#### The `content` as JSON

After understanding that the key in `{ "tags": { … } }` is just the part before the `=>`, I could reduce the final resource to the following block.

```
resource "aws_organizations_policy" "root-tag-policy" {
  name = "RootTagPolicy"
  description = "Tag policies, assigned to the root org."
  type = "TAG_POLICY"

  content = jsonencode({
    tags = {
      for key, tags in var.resource_tags : key => {
        tag_key = {
          "@@assign" = key
          "@@operators_allowed_for_child_policies" = ["@@none"]
        }
        tag_value = {
          "@@assign" = values( tags )
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

#### Quick test:

Add the following `output` statement after the `resource` block:

```
output "debug" {
  value = aws_organizations_policy.tp_root-tag-policy.content
}
```

Now `apply` (or `plan` or `refresh`) just this resource. It's faster this way. Then output the built `debug` from the `apply` or `refresh` run.

```sh
$ terraform apply -target=aws_organizations_policy.root-tag-policy
…things happening…
$ terraform output debug | json_pp
```

**ProTips:**

1. Pipe the output of the `output` directly into `json_pp` or `jq` so you can read it.
2. Use `jq .` if you want validation on top. If you see the output, it means it's valid. Else you should receive `0` as response.